# como puedo hacer que acepte decimales en mi divicion

Tags: java, matemáticas, intellij-idea

todo funciona bien pero cuando ingreso a un decimal no funciona el codigo ¿como puedo hacer que funcione?

```
    System.out.println("¿Cual es tu nombre?");
    String edaparcialdd = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Bienvenido de nuevo " + edaparcialdd);

    System.out.print("Introduce la Cal. del parcial 1\n");
    double num1 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Introduce la Cal. del parcial 2\n");
    double num2 = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("Introduce la Cal. del parcial 3\n");
    double num3 = sc.nextDouble();

    double sum = num1 + num2 + num3;
    double div = sum / 3;

    if (div >= 6) {
        System.out.println("El Alumno " + edaparcialdd);
        System.out.println("FUE APROBADO CON: " + div);
    } else {
        System.out.println("El Alumno " + edaparcialdd );
        System.out.println("NO FUE APROBADO CON: " + div);
    }

}}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no funciona?

Comment: Tu codigo lo probe por si acaso me estaba equivocando pero despues de verlo no veo que nada le falle.

Comment: Los decimales los colocas con puntos o comas??..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al utilizar sc.nextDouble() por defecto tienes que usar la coma (,) para separar la parte entera de la decimal, es decir, poner "7,5" y no "7.5"

Comment: Jaja gracias por aclararme esto. era muy tonto pero gracias bro